# Send notification e-mail to upstream committer in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, email-ext, jenkins-email-ext

Since Jenkins builds all of our projects automatically after we push to GitHub, we would like Jenkins to send out e-mail notifications if the build was successful or not at the end of the build pipline.

I created a shared library with the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def call(String buildStatus = 'STARTED') {
    // build status of null means successful
    buildStatus = buildStatus ?: 'SUCCESS'

    // Default values
    def subject = "JENKINS-NOTIFICATION: ${buildStatus}: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'"
    def details = """<p>${buildStatus}: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]':</p>
    <p>Check console output at &QUOT;<a href='${env.BUILD_URL}'>${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a>&QUOT;</p>"""

    // Send email to user who has started the build
    emailext(
        subject: subject,
        body: details,
        attachLog: true,
        compressLog: true,
        recipientProviders: [[$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider'], [$class:'UpstreamComitterRecipientProvider']]
    )
}
```

Note that I defined two `recipientProviders`. As far as I know the `RequesterRecipientProvider` should send an e-mail to the person who triggered the build manually at the Jenkins and the `UpstreamComitterRecipientProvider` should send an e-mail to the person who did the last git commit which triggered the build. ([source](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/email-ext/))

In the Jenkinsfile I loaded the library and I defined the sendNotification command in the post-block of the jenkinsfile:

```
#!groovy
@Library('shared-library@master') _

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('Checkout code base'){
            steps{
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        stage('do something'){
            steps{
                sh "do something"
            }
        }
        stage('do something'){
            steps{
                sh "do something"
            }
        }
    }
    post{
        always{
            sendNotifications currentBuild.result
        }
    }
}
```

Now e-mail notifications arrive when I manually trigger a build at Jenkins, but when I push to GitHub and Jenkins build gets triggered, no e-mail notification is sent. This is the log of the pipeline:

```
messageContentType = text/html; charset=UTF-8
Request made to attach build log
Request made to compress build log
Adding recipients from project recipient list
Sending email to upstream committer(s).
Adding recipients from trigger recipient list
Successfully created MimeMessage
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Some error occured trying to send the email...check the Jenkins log
```

Unfortunately, there is no further information at the Jenkins log. It seems to me, that `UpstreamComitterRecipientProvider` does not provide the e-mail address of the last committer as it should.

I have tried to use the `DevelopersRecipientProvider`, which sends e-mails to all developers in the project's commit history. This works just fine. Unfortunately the `UpstreamComitterRecipientProvider` does not.

Has anyone experienced similar problems? Am I missing something?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It is because of this line 
 recipientProviders: [[$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider'], [$class:'UpstreamComitterRecipientProvider']]
it actually gets information who triggered jenkins. When you doing it is fine.
But when jenkins email to send is null or not exists.You better do that via environment variable. Inside jenkins it is possible to create a group of emails to which you would like to send and then in your pipeline you will be calling it like this 
env.yourgroupvariablename this will give you your email list or group. After  add this to your email => to: env.yourgroupvariablename

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds kinda like you want `CulpritsRecipientProvider` or `DevelopersRecipientProvider` instead.

`UpstreamComitterRecipientProvider` looks at upstream builds, not the current one.

Comment: Works with the CulpritsRecipientProvider! Thanks.